# Why showed tuple index out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**The whole code:**

```
import os
import re
import pydicom
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import SimpleITK as sitk

# huaxi_dataset
FILE_ROOT = './149/'

# single_dataset

def tryint(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

def str2int(v_str):
    return [tryint(sub_str) for sub_str in re.split('([0-9]+)', v_str)]

stack_file = sorted([x for x in os.listdir(FILE_ROOT)])

for num, stack_dir in enumerate(stack_file):
    print('start cat {0} patient'.format(stack_dir))
    stacks = sorted([x for x in os.listdir(FILE_ROOT+stack_dir)])
    stack_data = []
    for loc, region_dir in enumerate(stacks):
        print('start read {} region data'.format(region_dir.split('_')[-1]))
        
        series_IDs = sitk.ImageSeriesReader.GetGDCMSeriesIDs(FILE_ROOT+stack_dir+'/'+region_dir)
        nb_series = len(series_IDs)
        print('The squence ID is {0}, with lenth: {1}'.format(series_IDs[0], nb_series))

        series_file_names = sitk.ImageSeriesReader.GetGDCMSeriesFileNames(FILE_ROOT+stack_dir+'/'+region_dir, series_IDs[0])
        
        series_reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()
        series_reader.SetFileNames(series_file_names)
        image3D = series_reader.Execute()

        print('The series {0}\n Shape: {1}\n Spacing: {2}\n Direction:{3}\n Origin: {4}'.format(
              series_IDs[0], image3D.GetSize(), image3D.GetSpacing(), image3D.GetDirection(), image3D.GetOrigin()))

        sitk.WriteImage(image3D, FILE_ROOT+stack_dir+'/'+region_dir+'/'+series_IDs[0]+'.nii.gz')
        print('Saving {0} squence stack, Finished!'.format(series_IDs[0]))

        if loc == 0:
            first_spacing = image3D.GetSpacing()
            first_origin = image3D.GetOrigin()
            first_direction = image3D.GetDirection()
        stack_data.append(sitk.GetArrayFromImage(image3D))
    #     print(sitk.GetArrayFromImage(image3D).shape)

        if loc == len(stacks)-1:
            whole_stack = np.stack(stack_data, axis=1)

            for seris in range(whole_stack.shape[0]):
                saved_image = sitk.GetImageFromArray(whole_stack[seris])
                saved_image.SetSpacing(first_spacing)
                saved_image.SetOrigin(first_origin)
                saved_image.SetDirection(first_direction)
                sitk.WriteImage(saved_image, FILE_ROOT+stack_dir+'/'+'seris_'+str(seris)+'.nii.gz')
print('Finish data tranform!')
```

And the error was

```
    print('The squence ID is {0}, with lenth: {1}'.format(series_IDs[0], nb_series))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

WARNING: In D:\a\1\sitk-build\ITK\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.cxx, line 67
GDCMSeriesFileNames (000002E08104D8A0): ./149/TF2D14_RETRO_IPAT_SHORTTR_0055/1 (1).IMA is not a directory

WARNING: In D:\a\1\sitk-build\ITK\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.cxx, line 100
GDCMSeriesFileNames (000002E08104D8A0): No Series were found
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of what happened:

```py
empty_tuple = tuple()
empty_tuple[0]
```

> IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 1 empty_tuple = tuple()
> ----> 2 empty_tuple[0]
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

An empty tuple has no elements, so any index value will be out of range. Given the warning

> No Series were found

it should not be too surprising that `series_IDs` is empty. Also look at the other warning to see how to perhaps fix this.